# Would asking "When could we call a system an AI" be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, tagging

I've the feeling this would be opinion based or too broad, so I come here for community review before writing a more complete question.

The root of the question is where to put the limit between "automated system" and "artificial intelligence".

For example, would an hybrid car able to start by itself a generator to charge back after a period of use/battery level could be called an artificial intelligence and if not at which point could we start talking about artificial intelligence ?

If this happen to be on-topic, which would be the relevant tags ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that there is at least one question like this on the site:

[Are Siri and Cortana AI programs?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/are-siri-and-cortana-ai-programs)

So I guess it would be okay - as long as you are asking **about one** (or two) **specific thing**(s).

For asking about in general when something is AI, that has already been asked: [What are the minimum requirements to call something AI?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/what-are-the-minimum-requirements-to-call-something-ai)

The tags... Now that's the problem. That might be worth its own Meta post.

And welcome to AI!

Comment: re: "as long as you are asking about one (or two) specific thing(s)." that's (sadly) the point, I was taking the opposite path about the _necessary_ features for a system to be called an AI, so maybe it is not specific enough (the car example was just to illustrate the idea and I don't feel opening a question for each thing would be of value) .

Comment: @Tensibai Duplicate: http://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/what-are-the-minimum-requirements-to-call-something-ai

Comment: Awww, missed it while searching before asking here :/

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what was said by Mithrandir, I would personally say it's best that such a question focus on **only one thing**. In other words, questions that ask about an aspect of each item in a big list of things would be less than ideal. In the case of Siri and Cortana (smart personal assistants, basically), they're very similar products, so it makes sense to have one question for them.

It would be even better if such questions included **specific features** of the objects/products that the question owner suspects may produce AI. That shows research effort, and in discovering the relevant features, the person who asks might stumble upon an interesting insight themselves. It also has the benefit of covering all products that have that feature (having wide applicability yet focused scope tends to mark great questions in my experience), so we might not even need to name Siri and Cortana in the question title.

Comment: I agree, the question could have been 'systems like siri or cortana' and by extent 'or alexa'. As I already said this question is reasonably scoped for a correct answer, mine was on the fence and at end was a dupe. Thanks for the insight for future readers BTW.

Comment: Correction: this though about scope never left my mind before, now it's done ;) Sorry for the double comment, my phone did give up on batteries